# Working in Netherlands for non EU citizens married to EU citizens

Tags: netherlands

I have EU (Bulgarian) passport and my wife is non-EU citizen (she has Macedonian passport). I should start working in Netherland next April (2019), so my question is:

Can my wife get working permission or social security number for work because of our marriage (she is married to EU citizen) and what is the procedure.

P.S. I will have an address on my name and social number as soon as i get in Netherlands.

I hope that you can help us with some information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The procedure is outlined on the website of the Immigration and Naturalization Service *(Immigratie en Naturalisatie Dienst,* IND).  I am unable to open the site right now to compose a proper answer, but basically your wife benefits from EU free movement when she is with you, so she has a legal right to live with you in the Netherlands with rights nearly as strong as those of Dutch citizens, including the right to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your partner should apply for the residence permit as a partner of EU/Switzerland citizen.

As I know, partners, no matter what nationality, will get a permit that allows working in the Netherlands. I even don't know if the Netherlands has a permit without working permission.

More info you will find [here](https://ind.nl/en/eu-eea).

Comment: The Bulgarian citizen cannot get a permit to work in the Netherlands because as an EU citizen he can get a document that permits him to work in the Netherlands from the Bulgarian authorities, namely his passport or national ID card.  The page you link to has a link on it to the page that applies here, but it would be better to link to it directly.

Comment: Thanks.  I still can't open the IND site, oddly, because of a certificate error that my phone browser won't let me bypass.  Perhaps I should post a question on [su] or [Android.SE].  (The residence card definitely allows employment, of course.)